# ¿Como mantengo el valor de un checkbox seleccionado en una paginacion? en java

Tags: java, jtable

Estoy trabajando en java web con jsp y necesito mostrar datos desde una BD en una tabla, acá debo seleccionar con un campo checkbox y  enviar los datos que selecciono a otro jsp, realice una paginación de la tabla con Data Tables, pero aquí cuando quiero elegir items de diferentes paginas, solo envía los items de la pagina que se esta visualizando, los demás check no se envían al jsp.

```
<form name="" method="post" action="Acta.jsp">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
      <tr>


        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Tipo</th>
        <th>Marca</th>
        <th>Modelo</th>
        <th>Numero Serie</th>
        <th>Persona Responsable</th>
        <th>Ubicacion</th>
        <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
        <th>Fuente Financiamiento</th>
        <th>Proyecto</th>
        <th>Numero Factura</th>

        <th>Valor</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Fecha Factura</th>
        <th>Agregar</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>




    <tbody>

    <%                  
      LinkedList<BeanMostrarBien> lista= ConsultarBien.consultarBien();
      for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++) {

        out.println("<tr>");

        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getCantidad()+    "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getTipoProducto()+    "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getMarca() +  "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getModelo() +     "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getNumeroSerie()+     "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getPersonaResponsable()+  "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getUbicacion()+   "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getFechaIngresoSistema()+  "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getFuenteFinanciamiento() +   "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getProyecto()+    "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getNumeroFactura()+   "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getValor()+   "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getEstado()+  "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + lista.get(i).getFechaFactura()+    "</td>");

        out.println("<td><center><input  id='agregarBien' type='checkbox' value="+lista.get(i).getId()+" name='agregarBien' ></center></td>");

        out.println("</tr>");            

      }

    %>

    </tbody>

  </table>
  <center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Generar Acta"></center>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
      select: {
        style: 'multi'
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la opción de enviar los datos por AJAX encaja en tu proyecto, lo más sencillo es serializar la tabla:

```
$('#form-submit').click( function(event) {

  var data = table.$('input').serialize();

  $.post( window.location.href, data).done(function(response){

    //código de éxito

  }).fail(function(){

    //código de error

  });

  return false;

});
```